# How to make like button stay as liked state when refresh the page

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm working on a Like button. It's working just fine unless user refresh the page. When page is not refreshed the like button itself change the style and add 1 to the like count if user click on it. But when the page is refreshed the like button remain the like count and the previous style then add 1 to the like count and change to the new style if user click on it. That's the problem.

The like button looks like this:

[image: Like button]

Here is the Javascript code:

```
function addLikes(id,action) {
    $.ajax({
    url: "like.php",
    data:'post_id='+id+'&action='+action,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data){
    var likes = parseInt($('#likes-'+id).val());
    switch(action) {
      case "like":
      $('#like_area'+id).html('<i id="like'+id+'" class="fas fa-thumbs-up react"></i> Thích');
      $('#like_area'+id).attr("onclick", "addLikes("+id+",'unlike')");
      likes = likes+1;
      $('#like_area'+id).addClass("liked");
      break;
      case "unlike":
      $('#like_area'+id).html('<i id="like'+id+'" class="far fa-thumbs-up react"></i> Thích');
      $('#like_area'+id).attr("onclick", "addLikes("+id+",'like')");
      $('#like_area'+id).removeClass("liked");
      likes = likes-1;
      break;
    }
    
    $('#likes-'+id).val(likes);
    if(likes>0) {
      $('#people_liked'+id).html(kFormatter(likes));
      $('#user_liked'+id).attr("style", "display:block;");
    } else {
      $('#user_liked'+id).attr("style", "display:none;");
    }
    }
    });
  }
```

Here is the PHP code in like.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/require/serverconnect.php';

$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
$action = $_POST['action'];

if(!empty($post_id)) {
switch ($action) {
    case 'like':
        $query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO tintuc_post_likes (username_of_like, liked_post_id) VALUES ('$username','$post_id')";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    break;
    
    case 'unlike':
        $query = "DELETE FROM tintuc_post_likes WHERE username_of_like = '$username' AND liked_post_id = '$post_id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    break;
}
}
?>
```

PHP Select code in index.php:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT tintuc_posts.id, tintuc_posts.author, tintuc_posts.content, tintuc_posts.timeofpost, tintuc_posts.has_comment, tintuc_posts.avatar, tintuc_posts.has_image, tintuc_posts.image, tintuc_posts.username, tintuc_posts.c4id, COUNT(tintuc_post_likes.like_id) as likes, GROUP_CONCAT(accounts.name separator '|') as liked_by
    FROM tintuc_posts
    LEFT JOIN tintuc_post_likes
    ON tintuc_posts.id = tintuc_post_likes.liked_post_id
    LEFT JOIN accounts
    ON tintuc_post_likes.username_of_like = accounts.username
    GROUP BY tintuc_posts.id
    ORDER BY tintuc_posts.id DESC";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 ?>
```

Here is the tables:
[image: newsfeed posts table]
[image: like table]

Comment: You have posted code on how to submit the like - this is working OK? When you load the page, you need to look and see if that user has liked it, and update the like status accordingly?

Comment: You have not shown any javascript  that reads the results from the sql query on pageload

Comment: I'm having a tough time understanding where the issue is. Is the value updated in the database?

Comment: @Simon Yes. Exactly what I need. The like submit is working fine.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius `<span id="people_liked<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"><?php echo number_format_short($row['likes']) ?></span>` It's in the PHP code.

Comment: I must be blind then @DươngTùngAnh as I cannot see that in the above code. Either way your code is wide open to SQL injection

Comment: @El_Vanja Yes. But as you can see in the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrpHu.png there is a duplicate in column liked_post_id. Normally there should be only one row that has username and liked post id. Or else it will be deleted when user click unlike.

Comment: Sorry @ProfessorAbronsius the code is not in the part I want to show. So what can I do to avoid the SQL injection?

Comment: so - you want to know how to set the initial page display to indicate the number/status of the `"likes"` yet you do not wish to show the code that would be of help in that process - is that about right? Wow... 
Anyway - to avoid, or at least help mitigate, SQL injection use `prepared statements` rather than take user variables and use them directly in the sql

Comment: I wanted to show it but it is too long. Anyway, I should use the $stmt -> bind_param(...) things, is that correct?

Comment: In your screenshot, you have the yellow thumb in the tool bar, is this what you want to be selected/highlighted when they page refresh? To show they have already liked it? In which case, when you do the code to draw that button, you need to get a list of users who have like it, and compare to the current user, and then if current user is in that list, add the "selected" class (or whatever you do on click initially) so the button looks selected.

Comment: @Simon I think you should answer this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is probably your answer:

In your screenshot, you have the yellow thumb in the tool bar, is this what you want to be selected/highlighted when they page refresh? To show they have already liked it?

Assuming this is the case, when you run the code to draw that button, you need to get a list of users who have like it, and compare to the current user, and then if current user is in that list, add the "selected" class (or whatever you do on click initially) so the button looks selected.

I am not a PHP developer, but in pseudo code would be something like:

```
var hasLiked = ListOfUserLinks.IndexOf(currentuserId) >= 0;
<button name="like" class="button <%hasLiked ? 'likedState' : ''%>" />
```

You can see you just adjust the classes based on whether the user has liked it, but it is done at page load time, as this is the initial state of the page.

Comment: Just an additional thought - ensure when you draw the button, if you want people to be able to "unlike" their liked item, then ensure you bind an "unlike" event, rather than the "like" event to the button.